# Passing an object as a parameter of a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

i am having an hard time understanding the usability of passing an object as a parameter of a function.

I am trying to learn to use Next.js and they usually have this way of interacting with their code.

Can someone explain me in short words the usability of it ? I have an example listed below.

Thank you !

```
function Page({ data }) {
  // Render data...
}
```

Understanding the usability of passing an object as an argument of a function.
Explained me with an example the usability of it.

Comment: Do you understand _object destructuring_?  (and _parameter destructuring_?)  What you have is similar to `function Page(obj) { let data = obj.data;  ... }`

Comment: Ok, so the object has to be predefined, i am simply destructuring before acessing it right ? I could simple acess the object inside of the function without destruction...

Answer (score 2):

This syntax is called [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

So `{ data }` in `function Page({ data }){ ...` is not an object definition, but a destructuring of the object passed as the first argument of the function,
which results in a variable `data` available in the function body.

### More details ...

#### Preface

I assume you are familiar with basic destructuring assignments, which look like e.g.:

```
const person = { name: 'Alice', age: 20 };  // <-- define object
const { name, age } = person;               // <-- destructure properties from the object
```

But note that you not necessarily need to bind this object to a variable name to be able to destructure it:

```
const { name, age } = { name: 'Alice', age: 20 };  // <-- define object and destructure it right away, without a variable name
```

#### Destructuring of arguments in React components

In a React function-component you can pass properties and access them inside the component like this:

```
function Page( props ) {
    return <div>
        Data: { props.data }
    </div>;
};

function App() {
    return <Page data="Hello" />;
};
```

You can also *destructure* the `props` at the beginning of the function, so that you don't have to type `props....` for each property:

```
function Page( props ) {
    
    const { data } = props;
    
    return <div>
        Data: { data }
    </div>;
};
```

React components always have the same arguments, so you basically always have the `props` argument. Here "props" is a variable name that is bound to the `props` object (which contains all the properties passed to the component).

But you almost never actually need the `props` object itself, you likely only want the properties inside it.

So you don't really *need* to bind the object with the properties to the name "props", only to destructure it right away in the next line,
which makes the `props` object obsolete for the rest of the function body.

For this, javascript has a "shortcut syntax" to destructure an argument directly in the function arguments section, without specifying a name for the argument:

```
function Page({ data }){
    return <div>
        Data: { data }
    </div>;
};
```

This is common syntax. I wouldn't say that it is better or worse than other options.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was great and one huge positive benefit of an object prop is you dont have to pass parameters in a specific order, which is super helpful when function argument list becomes long.

Answer (score 0):

This is called destructing. Works for objects and arrays:

```js
const obj = { x: 'hello', y: 'world', z: 'whats up' };
const { x } = obj;

console.log('obj.x is', obj.x);
console.log('x is', x);

const { y, z: myNewName } = obj;

console.log('obj.y is', obj.y);
console.log('y is', y);

console.log('obj.z is', obj.z);
console.log('myNewName is', myNewName);
// console.log(z) will error


const arr = ['value', v => console.log(v)];
const [whateverIWantToCallIt, namesDoNotMatterJustTheIndex] = arr;

console.log('accessing from deconstruction of arr')
console.log(whateverIWantToCallIt);
console.log(namesDoNotMatterJustTheIndex('whats up'));

console.log('accessing from arr')
console.log(arr[0]);
console.log(arr[1]('whats up'));
```